# Como conectar desde c# a sql server express usando ip?

Tags: c#, ip, sql-server-express

Estoy intentando hacer una conexion entre c# y sqlserver express y conectarme usando la ip de la maquina que actue como servidor por ejemplo tener 3 laptops conectadas por wifi y que una sea servidor y las demas se conecten a ella por medio de la ip
es decir estoy buscando la cadena de conexion por ejemplo ahorita tengo esto pero no me funciona(desde mi misma maquina cabe aclarar, obviamente tampoco desde otras) tambien aclarar que en propiedades->conexiones: ya esta habilitado permitir conexiones remotas...

```
public static string RutaConexion= @"Data Source = 192.168.x.x\\SQLEXPRESS,1433; Initial Catalog = base; Integrated Security = True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(RutaConexion);
```

De antemano gracias...

Comment: Que bonita práctica. Me gusta. Una pregunta... Qué has intentado? Las máquinas responden al ping? Qué error obtienes? Cuál es el problema específico?

Comment: Hola si, eso ya lo probamos y si al hacer ping obtenemos respuesta, pero si en la cadena de conexion pongo mi propia ip no me  conecta, me tirar error de instancia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La máquina que funcionará como servidor debe aceptar las conexiones entrantes puedes configurarlo de la siguiente manera:

Para configurar la base de datos de Microsoft SQL Server para el acceso remoto:

1.Inicie SQL Server Management Studio.

2.En el explorador de objetos, haga clic con el botón derecho sobre el servidor y seleccione Propiedades.

3.Haga clic en Conexiones.

4.Bajo Conexiones de servidor remoto, seleccione Permitir conexiones remotas con este servidor.

5.Haga clic en Aceptar para guardar los cambios. No hace falta reiniciar el servidor después de cambiar este ajuste.

6.Asegúrese de que los protocolos TCP/IP están activados y que el firewall está ajustado para permitir el puerto 1433. Para obtener más información sobre activar la TCP/IP, consulte Configurar Microsoft SQL Server.

[Puedes obtener más información en el siguiente enlace](https://help.ivanti.com/wl/help/es_ES/AVA/6.2/Avalanche/Install/postgreSQLRemoteAccess.htm)

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, esta configuracion de permitr conexion remotas si ya esta hecha

Comment: Ok, veo que en tu cadena de conexión usas la seguridad integrada, eso te podría dar problemas al intentar conectarte desde otra máquina. Puedes intentar con una cadena parecida a esta: Data Source=192.168.0.1;Initial Catalog=master;User ID=sa;Password=TuContraseña;

Comment: si al instalar no configure el usuario sa si no que solo deje autenticacion de windows, puedo simplemente obviar eso de integrated security? es decir no ponelo?

Comment: No soy experto en el tema, pero lo que entiendo es que con la seguridad integrada de windows, toma tu información de la sesión y con esa ingresas, pero si intentas conectarte desde otra máquina la información de sesión no será igual por lo tanto no te podrás conectar, así que deberías usar la autenticación de sql server.

Comment: ok ahorita me pondre a ver eso, yo tampoco soy experto y me ayuda mucho tu comentario, gracias